# Do the quotes from the "Bottom Half of the Internet" exist?

Tags: realism, dave-gorman, modern-life-is-goodish

In Dave Gorman's *Modern Life is Goodish*, once per episode he performs a "Found Poem" as he calls it. This is a compilation of humourously angry and nonsensical comments about an unnecessarily controversial topic (possibly being sensationalised in the tabloids) that Dave has scoured from the "bottom half of the Internet".

However, I have searched for several of these comments on [Google](https://www.google.com) and not managed to find any.

My question is, are the comments Dave is quoting genuine? I realise that *Modern Life Is Goodish* finished production quite a few years ago and so these comments might have since disappeared from wherever Dave and his team found them, but I'd expect to find a few lingering, the Internet being what it is...

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Dave obviously means the sleazy parts of the internet with rude comments, offensive people killing each other with words etc etc. And yes, it exists. Always did and always will, it is just part of the internet.

Comment: I'm asking if the specific comments referenced by Dave are genuine. I've edited my question to clarify

Comment: So please write out those quotes, people can't be expected to go look for transcript of the show to see what you mean.

Comment: There doesn't seem much point... there could be hundreds of them. I don't expect people to look through transcripts of the programme, and if I did paste them in I wouldn't expect them to go searching for the individual quotes. But if someone happens to know the answer, or have inside information, they might be kind enough to share.

Comment: This is a *ten year old* show. Expecting those comments to still be there now and expecting them to be findable through Google is futile.

Answer (score 6):

OP asks:

> are the comments Dave is quoting genuine?

TL;DR:

A mix of Yes, modified, and unverifiable.

As written below, it looks like some can be used without modification, some get tweaked and some may exist but might be a mix of all the above. And whilst it is possible to make up comments completely, given the vastness of the internet and the people on it, it seems he might not have to.

....

Whilst hiding from the family i had a quick look at

*Dave Gorman Modern Life is Goodish S3 E1 | Found Poem - Double Yolk Eggs*

Which can be easily found on Youtube.

I saw this screen:

[image]

and located the 5 articles shown on screen:

[image]

Of the 5:

- 1 was pay walled so I was unable to read it or see the comments.
- 1 had 135 comments and the other had 288.

Of the two available with comments to read, I got two hits:

[image]

[image]

and one partial:

[image]

The very long conversations that drew a lot of the laughs, may or may not have been attached to the article i was unable to read.

As the articles are very old, perhaps the comments sections of the others had been removed, i decided not to check that far.

From the above, there is nothing to say that they are entirely made up, as at least one comment is entirely intact.

There is also nothing to stop him from tweaking a comment to far greater effect for his use, and this would be typical of how Found Poetry is created.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/ModernLifeIsGoodish indicates that he will make up material - he is not making a documentary after all.

Gorman is mentioned as an example in Wiki for Found Poetry where:

> ...a type of poetry created by taking words, phrases, and sometimes whole passages from other sources and reframing them by *making changes* in spacing and lines, or by *adding or deleting* text, thus imparting new meaning.

And lastly, of course those articles shown on screen might not be the only articles he read to get those quotes from.

Also read the blog article:

http://gormano.blogspot.com/2017/

indicates whilst working with other writers he is mostly responsible for his own material, showing the work (long hours and research for a start) that goes in to the powerpoints for example.